# /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:43: FutureWarning:

Tags: python

I have written the below code for data visualization

plt.figure(figsize = (15,30))
for i in enumerate(feature):
plt.subplot(6, 3, i[0]+1)
sns.countplot(i[1], hue = 'Loan_Status', data = Loan_data )

but having the below:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/seaborn/_decorators.py:43: FutureWarning:

Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.

Any help on how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 0):

The warning itself is pretty harmless, but if you wanted it gone you can insert the following code to filter it out:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Learned it from [this helpful documentation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-futurewarning-messages-in-scikit-learn/) on machine learning mastery.